# Como atribuir a uma variavel os resultados de um array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou recebendo vários horários em uma função, ao chamar a função no `Controller` uso o `foreach` e queria que esses resultados(horários) seja impresso na tela para o usuário ver, mas usando o `echo` não consigo imprimir só com o `var_dump`, mas quero que apareça na tela só horários sem `var_dump`.

Código do `Model`:

```
public function select_horarios_selecionados($data, $horarios=array()){
    if(is_array($horarios)){
        foreach($horarios as $key){

            $this->db->select('hora');
            $this->db->where('dia', $data);
            $this->db->where('hora', $key);
            $query = $this->db->get('agendamentos')->result();
            $horarios_selecionados[] = array();

            if($query){
                foreach($query as $value){
                    $horarios_selecionados[] = $value->hora;                        
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $horarios_selecionados;
    }

}
```

Código do `Controller`

```
if($consulta = $this->agenda->select_horarios_selecionados($data, $horarios)){
                foreach($consulta as $linha){
                    $horarios_ocup = $linha;
                    var_dump($horarios_ocup);
                }

            }else{
                echo "Data e horarios diponiveis para agendamento";
            }
```

RESULTADO QUE APARECE NA TELA:

```
array(0) { } string(8) "09:00:00" array(0) { } string(8) "09:30:00"
```

Quero que apareça só os horarios exemplo: `09:00:00 09:30:00`

Comment: usa o foreach, verifica na documentação, lá exemplos de como fazer a exibição sem mostrar o array completo, apenas com a formatação que deseja.  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Já estou utilizando o Foreach mas não deu certo

Comment: Então verifica esta função str_replace, mas irá dar mais trabalho: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Por favor já vi essa documentação, preciso de ajuda de alguém que posa me dar um exemplo e uma breve explicação, não precisa dar o código pronto.

Comment: Como uso echo para ver só os horarios limpos 09:00:00 com echo sem dar var_dump? pois o var_dump tem as informações de array e indice de array

Comment: O lugar correto da dar `echo` não seria a view em vez do controller? E esse é todo o código do controller?

Comment: tenta `$horarios_selecionados = array();` porque aqui você está criando uma lista não é? no php tu pode criar uma lista `$list[]` como `$list = array()` no caso como voce fez me parece uma dentro da outra. Sinceramente não sei explicar, pois não testei aqui.

Comment: Já fiz dessa Forma Eduardo e não deu certo.
Estou dando echo no controller apenas para teste mesmo.

Comment: O que aparece quando você faz print_r($linha) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem simples, vou adaptar seu código colocando comentários de algumas mudanças que realizei, veja:

Código do `Model`:

```
public function select_horarios_selecionados($data, $horarios=array()) {
    if(is_array($horarios)) {

        /* Mudei aqui o lugar aonde estava sendo criado o array,
           se criar dentro do loop foreach você vai perder os dados
           toda vez que reiniciá-lo. E tirei os [] da declaração da variável. */

        $horarios_selecionados = array();

        foreach($horarios as $key){

            $this->db->select('hora');
            $this->db->where('dia', $data);
            $this->db->where('hora', $key);
            $query = $this->db->get('agendamentos')->result();

            if(is_array($query)) {
                foreach($query as $value) {
                    $horarios_selecionados[] = $value->hora;                        
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $horarios_selecionados;
    }

}
```

Código do `Controller`:

```
/* Aqui você irá receber um array de strings, basta fazer um foreach
   usando echo para imprimir a variável do laço. Concatenei um espaço
   vazio para não sair todos os horário colados. */

$consulta = $this->agenda->select_horarios_selecionados($data, $horarios);
if(is_array($consulta)){
    foreach($consulta as $linha){
        echo $linha . ' ';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Não foi possível recuperar os horários';
}
```

Comment: MUito Obrigada Pedro pela ajuda rodou certinho aqui, agora vou estudar cada linha do código, sou estudante e me bato muito com arrays, foi de grande ajuda :)

Comment: De nada, que bom que lhe ajudou.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar a função `print_r($array)`.

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php